# Understanding how to deal with file deletions in Git

Tags: git, file, merge, rebase

I recently got a problem with git when one of my pushes got reverted on `origin/master`, but I stayed in my branch to continue my feature until it was ready for the final push. When I tried to `git pull --rebase`, some of my local changes were completely deleted due to the revert. However with pull merge I was able to push my local files that were deleted on `origin/master` because it triggered a conflict.

I tried to reproduce this with local branches, but was unsuccessful. I created file `a` on branch `develop`, merged it into `master`, deleted file `a` from `master`, added file `b` on `develop`, and tried to merge `master` into `develop`.

At this point I was expecting the merge to generate a conflict between the `master`'s deleted file `a` and develop's existing file `a`, but it just deleted the develop's file `a` just as my pull `--rebase` did in my original problem. Why?

Comment: Why do you expect it to generate a conflict? You didn't change anything on `develop` which must be merged with `master`'s changes (deletion). Merging it just applies the deletion back to develop. If you on the other hand had just changed file `a` on `develop` prior to merge, it possibly creates a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common behavior and already described in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented).

First, why did your reproduction **not create merge conflicts**?

> During a merge, the working tree files are updated to reflect the result of the merge. Among the changes made to the common ancestor’s version, **non-overlapping ones (that is, you changed an area of the file while the other side left that area intact, or vice versa)** are incorporated in the final result verbatim.

The next sentence in the same paragraph describes why a merge conflict was created by pulling `origin` without `--rebase` to your master:

> When **both sides made changes to the same area**, however, Git cannot randomly pick one side over the other, and asks you to resolve it by leaving what both sides did to that area.

A merge conflict - in your case - is not created, as only one of the both sides which are merged together affected that file. If you had changed the file `a` in `develop` prior to merging `master` onto that branch, it would have created a merge conflict, as your `pull` did. There you changed the file which was deleted on `origin` and this creates a merge conflict.